# When they say "merge CAF tag", merge into which kernel?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel

As far as I understood, CAF tags are tags into a Code Aurora git repo. Each tag is for a SoC and a specific android version. There are multiple repos with different drivers, but all those repos will have that same tag.

I have to merge these repos into my kernel, so I get the drivers and other modifications merged into my kernel.

But.... Which kernel? Which kernel do I start with? And how do I know how many repos are there for that kernel so I can merge all of them?